# How to set Airbrake with drupal 8

Tags: drupal, airbrake

I'm trying to use Airbrake with my drupal 8 project, I follow this GitHub page `https://github.com/akalsey/airbrake-drupal`. I create an account and install the Airbrake using Composer `composer require airbrake/phpbrake`. Then it says that I should copy this snippet into your PHP app

```
$notifier = new Airbrake\Notifier(array(
    'projectId' => ****,
    'projectKey' => '****'
));

Airbrake\Instance::set($notifier);

$handler = new Airbrake\ErrorHandler($notifier);
$handler->register();
```

But I don't know in which file I past it? 
Any help?

Comment: I think it's fine to put it at the top of drupal's index.php.

Comment: @EricLavault I try what you said, but the site crashed.

Comment: You'll need to include the library files before calling the constructor. You can also register the error handler in a .module file, as long as the module is enabled.

Comment: @EricLavault which library files and which module you mean?

Comment: I mean the airbrake library! it must be loaded first, so *after* the line `$autoloader = require_once 'autoload.php';` to be correct. If you want to register the error handler from a module it's fine, any module is ok as soon as it's enabled. In fact, the idea is to put the code in a file that is parsed early and at every request.

Comment: @EricLavault I follow these instructions on github page "https://github.com/akalsey/airbrake-drupal" but the library don't have src folder only thses (README.md,airbrake.info,airbrake.module)?

Comment: This one is for drupal 7

Comment: @EricLavault so where you found the libraries and modules for Drupal 8, because I only found this?

Comment: There is some confusion : `airbrake/phpbrake` *is* the library but still classes must be required before you can use them, so if you put the code before the mentioned line (autoload), you'll need to include classes manually, not otherwise as long as the lib is required as a dependency. There is no drupal 8 module, and having a dedicated drupal module is not required.